# How to get a logfile and display it using JavaScript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, logging, xmlhttprequest

I have a logfile that has a couple entries separated by newlines, but when I try to get it using this code:

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};

xhttp.open("GET","https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/paramt/MemeAdviser/memeadviser.log");
xhttp.send();
```

It isn't separated by newlines. How do I display each entry on a separate line? When I used `curl`, it displayed each entry on a new line

[Here is my log file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/paramt/MemeAdviser/memeadviser.log)

Comment: You have two choices - you can append a `<br>` tag to the end of every line, or place your log contents between `<pre></pre>` tags. New line characters are removed in the browser, you emulate those with `<br>`;

Comment: Using `<pre></pre>` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Randy Casburn I found out that using `<pre></pre>` keeps newlines intact